# Namespace alias in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

I use c++11 while I need some classes from c++17 library. When using boost from which classes were added I wish to do the following:

```
#if __cplusplus < CPP17
using std::any = boost::any;  
#endif
```

Such alias is not allowed. Also extending the std namespace causes  [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std). I wish my code to look the same regardles of the c++ version. Is there a clear way?

Comment: Just use your own name and assign `boost::any` or `std::any` to it as needed?

Answer (score 8):

The clear way is to add a customized name for it.

```
#if __cplusplus < CPP17
using my_any = boost::any;
#else
using my_any = std::any;    
#endif

// using my_any...
```

Comment: I whish to use std::any for c++17 compatibility .

Comment: @Ariel As you realized, it's not possible to "modify" std namespace legally.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you're attempting to create a type alias within a namespace. The corect syntax for that is:

```
namespace namespace_name {
    using any = boost::any;
}
```

However, the standard disallows adding definitions (there are exceptions for template specializations) into `std` namespace, so if you tried to define `std::any`, the behaviour of your program will be undefined.

Using any namespace, including the global one is OK, but not the ones reserved to the implementation, which includes `std` and its subnamespaces.

Comment: I tried to add definitions in std namespace and it was compiled.

Comment: @Ariel I've amended my answer. Definitions in `std` do not make the program ill-formed, it makes the behaviour undefined. That said, being ill-formed isn't guaranteed to prevent the program from compiling.

Comment: It is very sad that when I switch from old c++ version to new one I have to change all 'boost' in 'std'.

Comment: Maybe some scripts will allow to change name?

Comment: @Ariel You can use a preprocessor macro to create a typedef for either boost, or standard depending on the standard version.

Comment: Could you provide an example as an answer?

Comment: @Ariel it seems that songyuanyao's answer already has an example of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the big deal with undefined behavior worries. You use an #if to check for C++17 already, and you know there's no `any` before that. If you really want this, I say go for it, and place the alias in std if it's earlier than C++17.

At the end of the day, helper functions/classes/etc will likely be placed in another namespace or prefixed with __ because that's available to standard libraries. I don't think any implementation of pre-C++17 exports `any` in std.

There's no other way. Just ignore "undefined behavior" and go for it if it works. There's nothing magical about it ruining your code; worst that can happen is a bad std implementation will conflict and fail to compile when you define the alias. Some people overblow undefined behavior issues in my opinion.