# C++: Refactoring managing namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++14, rename

I am refactoring a widely used class. Given how widely it is used, my intend is to create a version 2 of the class. I will keeping the interfaces same/similar [I am forced to make some changes, otherwise it will become ugly with new changes] so that switching from old class to new class becomes easy. And we can switch applications using the old class to new class one by one.

Now I am not sure how to manage name / namespace in this case.

Eg:

Currently, lets say, the class is under a namespace `'app'`

```
namespace app {

    class Important {

        ...
    };
}
```

I would like to keep the class name same or very similar so that the meaning is clear.

```
namespace app {

   // This looks okay (conveys the meaning), but is ugly.

   class Important2 {
      ...
   };
}

namespace app {

   namespace v2 {

       // I think this will be confusing. It will given a feeling that the v2 
       // applies to app namespace. There are lot of classes under 'app' 
       // namespace which are not changed.
       class Important {

       };
   }
};
```

Is there a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Take the class name and look up a synonym for it and use that, or nest a namespace within this app namespace and then declare the function with the same name in the nested namespace.

Comment: ABI stability matter?  Is the bame highly unique?  Can you do sweeps of old code, renaming *old* type?

Comment: @Yakk It's header only library / class. So it is fine I guess. I can rename old type everywhere. But the name is something everyone 'knows'. So changing to 'important2' still preserves the meaning and I a leaning towards that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to your problem is to used the [gof factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), where you have an interface and a number of implementations for example Important, Important2 etc.
You could then tell your consumer that you will be deprecating Important soon but a compiler warning

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve via simple *namespace alias*.
A sample could be in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41420638/781933, for a *switch on/off* approach (driving migrations on a per-project base).

If instead you have to go through intermediate compositions rather than a complete replacement you could adopt intermediate solutions with compositions and [*inline namespaces*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016220/what-are-inline-namespaces-for#11018418).

You can find a specific example of version management via namespacing in the Stroustrup's ***The C++ Programming Language***.